# What is the difference between web and app network status in same device

Tags: react-native, networking, device

It seems like that my iOS App loses packets but in website (in Chrome) does not in same device. Is there any notable differences in network status between web and app in a same device?

The circumstances are in iPhone, iPad, Chrome, react-native.

Network info api in react-native is not quite useful in this situation.

Comment: Web apps usually run over to, what has automatic retransmissions. What protocol does your native app use?

Comment: Thanks @Ferrybig . My App use just http and later socket.io (maybe with feathersjs).